# Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ equal to zero in terms of x and y

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

The original equation: $x^2 - xy + y^2 = 3$

After Implicit Differentiation:
$\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = (-2x+y)(-x+2y)$

If I want to find $x$ and $y$ when $ \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = 0$ how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Solve -2x + y = 0 and -x + 2y = 0. The values where the two equations equal zero is where dy/dx will equal zero as well. Although, as mentioned above, one or the other will be zero, and since anything multiplied by zero is zero, the whole equation will equal zero.

Comment: Yes but how do I solve for only x when there is a y value there too?

Answer (score 1):

$dy/dx$ is the slope at all the tangents. When $dy/dx = 0 $ so is the slope,

so when $(-2x + y )( -x+2y) = 0 $ either $-2x +y= 0$ or $-x+2y=0$ (as the product of two non-zero numbers cannot be zero). You basically have a very simple simultaneous equation to solve for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Yes but how do I solve for only x when there is a y value there too?

Comment: Isolate and fill back into original equation.